# Can't log in to Ubuntu guest after upgrading to VirtualBox 5.2.6

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

After upgrading to VirtualBox 5.2.6 from 5.2.4, I can no longer log in on X, although tty logins are still fine.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

I found this in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[   104.538] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[   104.538] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[   104.551] (EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: _glapi_tls_Dispatch)
[   104.551] (EE) GLX: could not load software renderer
[   104.551] (II) GLX: no usable GL providers found for screen 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the VirtualBox website:

#### Important: The Guest Additions which come with VirtualBox 5.2.6 and 5.1.32 do not work properly on Linux guests with 3D enabled. Here are updated versions for [5.2.6](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.2.7-120528.iso) and [5.1.32](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.1.33-120670.iso).

After installing the new guest additions, X started up fine and I was able to log in again under X